# What is the design alternative to InitiateSystemShutdownEx?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

MSVC is giving me the following warning:

> Warning   C28159  Consider using 'a design alternative' instead of 'InitiateSystemShutdownExW'. Reason: Rearchitect to avoid Reboot

What does this mean? Couldn't find anything specific about it on the Internet. It's also recommending against other functions (ExitWindowsEx, InitiateSystemShutdown). What is the intended way to close the system?

I'm using code from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shutdown/displaying-the-shutdown-dialog-box) (except with the "Ex" function):

```
BOOL result = InitiateSystemShutdownEx(NULL, message, 31, FALSE, FALSE, SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OTHER | SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_OTHER | SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED);
```

on Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 17.9.0

I've tried original code from MSDN website. I've tried other WINAPI shutdown functions. I googled the error text. I was expecting to get rid of the warning.

Comment: It's saying that asking for a reboot is very heavy handed & you should see if there is an alternative - for example restarting a specific process rather than the whole machine.

Comment: I don't want to reboot. I want to shut down the computer for good.

Comment: Then ignore the warning with a `#pragma warning(disable:28159)`.

Comment: Use `ExitWindows` and its friend instead, which are the recommended APIs to shutdown the system..

Comment: @Faguss - The annotation just means you shouldn't do this but you can remove the warning. @jtxkopt - `ExitWindows` is a macro defined as `ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF, 0xFFFFFFFF)` so it doesn't shutdown nor reboot. And `ExitWindowsEx` is annotated as *"Consider using 'InitiateSystemShutdownEx' instead, rearchitect to avoid Reboot"* so it's exactly the same.

Comment: This should be new. I don't remember that I got this warning before.